# Waves and Antenns

Tags: antenna, wave

What is meant when someone says that a wave is linear and reciprocal, and also what is meant by antennas are linear, bilateral and passive

Comment: At least tell me why I am getting a vote down

Comment: Not my downvote, but it might help if you give some examples of where these terms are used.

Comment: @The Photon, thanks, at least I know what to do now